# How to scrape a complex table which has columns spanning multiple rows (a pedigree chart) in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I've looked at all the other related Stack Overflow questions, and none of them are close enough to what I'm trying to do to be useful. In part because, while some of those questions address dealing with tables where the leftward columns span multiple rows (as in a pedigree chart), they don't address how to handle the messy HTML which is somehow generating the chart. When I try the usual ways of ingesting the table with `rvest` it really doesn't work.

The table I'm trying to scrape looks like this:
[image: My pedigree chart]

When I extract the HTML of the first row (tr) of the table, I see that it contains: Betty, Jack, Bo, Bob, Jim, Dan, b 1932 (the very top of the table).

Great, you say, but not so fast. Because with this structure there's no way to know that Betty's mom is Sue (because Sue is on a different row).

Sue's row doesn't include Betty, but instead starts with Sue herself.

So in this example, Sue's row would be: Sue, Owen, Jacob, Luca, Blane, b 1940.

Furthermore, the row #2 in the HTML is actually just Ava b 1947.

I.e., the here's the content of each HTML row:

[image: This is how the HTML is organized:]

I tried using rvest to download the page and then extract the table.

A la:

`pedigree <- read_html(page) %>% html_nodes("#PedigreeTable") %>% html_table`

It really didn't work. Oddly, I got every column duplicated twice--so not too bad, but I'd rather it be a tibble/dataframe/matrix with the first column being 32 Bettys, and then the next column be 16 of each of Jack and Sue, etc...

I hope this is all clear as mud!

Ideally, as far as output, I'd get a nice neat dataframe with the columns person, father, mother. Like so: [image: how I'd like it to look]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the link to website so we can test the code and help you better?

Comment: Oh, duh, yeah that would be easier. Sorry, it was very late at night and my brain wasn't working properly. https://www.allbreedpedigree.com/colonels+smoking+gun

Answer (score 0):

Maybe writting a algorithm can do it, like :

```
Select only the last two columns : 

father_name=first value of the penultimate column

then browse the column to find the next non-NA value, count each rows

count=1 + number of NA values

mother_name=second non NA value

then count all rows until you find a name
count=count + 1 +  number of NA values
```

[image: Step1]

```
Create your final table with : 
name | father | mother

Isolate all the family's child names, and save them in your final table.
Assign father_name and mother_name in corresponding columns in your final table
```

[image: Step2]

```
Delete all rows used and start again.
```

[image: Step3]

```
Once you have assigned all the last column-people to their parents, delete the last column. 

Then, delete all blank rows to have a structure similar to the one needed in the fist step, and start the algorithm again
```

[image: Step4]

Hope that helps !!

PS : I suggest that you give an unique ID to each person at some point, to avoid confusion between people that have the same name.